# Easiest & cheapest way to use embedded filesystem on SD card

Tags: embedded, sd, data-storage

I want to build a cheap, basic project which logs data to an SD card that can be removed and read using a normal card reader in a computer.

Requirements are fairly basic so performance is not critical but simple would be good to enable a smaller device.

What is the best way to implement this? I guess something like FAT16? Are there free libraries for something like this?

Comment: Probably, but we need some more information. What microcontroller will you be using? What language / compiler will you use for programming? How large will your SD card be?

Comment: Ditto above plus how fast is the data arriving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [openLog datalogger](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9530)? It probably already does what you want.

It uses an ATmega328P, a microSD card socket, and not much else. It has a very simple serial command set. Normally, anything you send simply gets written to a text file on the SD card. It supports FAT16 and FAT32 using [sdfatlib](http://code.google.com/p/sdfatlib/).

[image]
<sub><sup>Image credit: Sparkfun.com</sup></sub>

It's [open source](https://github.com/sparkfun/OpenLog/wiki/design-files), so if you want to modify it, you should be able to do so pretty easily.